# Add items from select option to list, and put them back

Tags: jquery

I have a select option, a list and a button. When the button is clicked it removes the selected option and put it in the list. And when the li in the list is clicked, it is put back in the select option and it removes itself. Here is my code:

```
                            <select id="selLanguage" >
                                 <option value="1">English</option>
                                 <option value="2">Spanish</option>
                                 <option value="3">German</option>
                            </select>

                             <ul id="ulLanguage">
                             </ul>

                             <button id="btnAddLanguage">Language</button>
```

---

```
            //ADD LANGUAGE
            $(function() {
                $("#btnAddLanguage")
                .button()
                .click(function() {

                    $("#ulLanguage").append("<li id='"+$("#selLanguage :selected").val()+"' onclick='remove(this);' style='cursor:pointer'>"+$("#selLanguage :selected").text() +" </li>");
                    $("#selLanguage option[value='"+$("#selLanguage :selected").val()+"']").remove();


                });
            });
            //REMOVE LANGUAGE
            $("#ulLanguage").on("click","li", function(){

                $("select#selLanguage").append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"' >"+$(this).text()+"</li>");
                $(this).remove();
            });
```

It works, but when i add the three options, i remove the three optiones and they are put back in the select (till here is ok), and i add one again and it removes all the options in the select, instead just the one selected. I dont have any clue about where i made my mistake and Im very new to jquery, so i had to ask this. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: any particular reason why you are using on() for removing a language?

Comment: $("#ulLanguage li").click(function() { ... }); should be good enough

Comment: @user1565195 Yes, there is a reason, Event Delegation.

Comment: right that slipped my mind, good one :)

Comment: Try in remove language to change with this: `$("select#selLanguage").append("<option value='"+$(this).index()+"' >"+$(this).text()+"</option>");`I think that `$(this).val()` is ever equal to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things missing:

- Your second callback is outside the jquery ready callback
- You inject back into the select an option which is closed as a li:

append("<**option** value='"+$(this).val()+"' >"+$(this).text()+"</**li**>");

- You don't preserve the li.id value when you put back the item in the select, thus the error.

A corrected version is below

```
        $(function() {
            $("#btnAddLanguage")
            .on('click', function() {

                $("#ulLanguage").append("<li id='"+$("#selLanguage :selected").val()+"' style='cursor:pointer'>"+$("#selLanguage :selected").text() +" </li>");
                console.log($("#selLanguage :selected").val());
                $("#selLanguage option[value='"+$("#selLanguage :selected").val()+"']").remove();


            });

        //REMOVE LANGUAGE
        $("#ulLanguage").on("click","li", function(){

            $("select#selLanguage").append("<option value='"+$(this).attr('id')+"' >"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
            $(this).remove();
        });                 
        });
```